# Can't make ids work in Python! Help needed for Kivy newbie

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, ids

I know that you will think I am an absolute newbie - and you are right!! Maybe some of you will be so kind as to help me anyway :)

I am making a little homedevice with a screen for controlling and running the lights (Phillips Hue), showing the weather an so forth.

I have made a script for running the lights which works fine. I am now trying to build an interface as well. The interface should update the buttonstates on the run as the script runs in the background.

I am trying to create a function that will update the lights on a regular basis using the clock function in Kivy. A have tried using Properties, I have tried using ids but no matter what I try I get errors. I see that people often have trouble referencing Kivy widgets and it seems that the errors are somewhat different and requires more insight than I have in the way Kivy builds and run.

So maybe some of you pros can help point out the things that I am doing wrong! I have included the affected parts of the kv file as well as pseudocode that shows the structure of my app.

KV file:

```
<FrontPage>:

canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'tapet2.jpg'

GridLayout:
    rows: 3
    cols: 1
    size: root.width * 1, root.height * 1

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.35
            text: "VH54 appen"
            font_size: 30

        Label:
            text: ""

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 5
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20
        size_hint_y: 3
        ToggleButton:
            id: alrum_knap
            text: 'Alrum'
            on_state: root.alrum_knap(self.state)
```

... (goes on with other layout stuff)

Python Code:

```
from kivy.app import App, Widget    
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
    
class FrontPage(Widget):
        
    def update_alrum_knap(self):
        ( ... Code that defines alrum_on True or False)
        if alrum_on == True:
            FrontPage().ids.alrum_knap.state = 'down'
        else:
            FrontPage().ids.alrum_knap.state = 'normal'

    def alrum_knap(self, state):
        if state == 'down':
            Hue.ongroup(alrum_gr, sc_dag_alrum, 10)
        else:
            Hue.offgroup(alrum_gr, 20)

    def loop(self):
       (Contains code for running the lights)

class Vh54App(App):
    
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(FrontPage.loop, 0.5)
        Clock.schedule_interval(FrontPage.update_alrum_knap, 0.5)
        return FrontPage()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Vh54App().run()
```

I am thankful for all the help and insight I can get from you. I am perfectly aware that I have made all kinds of newbie errors! I am better at other things in life, but this is rather fun also :D

Regards
Simon, Denmark

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
FrontPage().ids.alrum_knap.state = 'down'
```

The `FrontPage()` is creating a new instance of `FrontPage`, which is not the instance that appears in your GUI. Whenever you use a classname (like `FrontPage`) followed by `()`, you are creating a new instance of that class.

Since that code is in a method of the `FrontPage` class, you can simply use the `self` parameter, like this:

```
self.ids.alrum_knap.state = 'down'
```

Also, your use of `FrontPage.loop` and `FrontPage.update_alrum_knap` in the `build()` method is incorrect. You should again be using the instance of `FrontPage`, like this:

```
def build(self):
    fp = FrontPage()
    Clock.schedule_interval(fp.loop, 0.5)
    Clock.schedule_interval(fp.update_alrum_knap, 0.5)
    return fp
```

You will also need to add `dt` arguments to those methods called by `Clock`.

Comment: John, you are my hero!!!! It all makes sense and it all works now! - actually I sort of got your point about creating an additional instance myself, but what I missed was the part about adding "dt" for both functions called by the clock to make it work. If it weren't for the virus I would hug you - I've been fooling around with this for hours and hours. Thank you SO much :D :D Thank you!

Comment: Okay I have just one followup question. It appears to me that changing the state of a button as in the code above also activates the "on_state" code in kv file. Is it possible to just change the state of the button without actually "pressing" the button?

Comment: I don't think there is any reasonable way to avoid the `on_state` event. But you could set a flag (something like `self.ignore_on_state=True`) just before you change the state, then your `alrum_knap()` method could check for that flag and, if `True`, just reset it to `False` and return. Care would be needed to be sure you don't set that flag unless you are actually changing the state.

Comment: Yes, well that is a possible solution. It turned out though, that if I use the "on_press" instead of "on_state" in the kv file for linking back to function in Python, it doesn't run the code when I change the state :) Thanks again for helping me out!